# Keybinding with single CTRL but not CTRL-SHIFT in atom

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, atom

I wonder if someone could spot where I'm going wrong.
I am trying to add a key with a single CTRL to delete a line.
My **keymap.cson** has

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-D': 'editor:delete-line'   
  'ctrl-M': 'editor:delete-line'
  'ctrl-shift-D': 'editor:delete-line'
  'ctrl-shift-M': 'editor:delete-line'
```

Ctrl-shift-D and M work whilst ctrl-D and M don't
(Apologies if a duplicate!).

Comment: Shift+supr deletes a line

Comment: interesting. Thas doesnt do anything on my setup.